# react-email-editor loadDesign dynamically with fetch data

Tags: reactjs

I try to integrate the react-email-editor as a component.
It only works if i use design defined as const.

This is the sample
https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor/blob/master/demo/src/example/index.js

I have no deeper experience with reactjs useRef.
I tried different ways to load the data, but without success:

- loading the data in a wrapper component and passing it as props
- handle the data with useEffect and useState

Is there a successful sample?

```
  ...

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  
  const emailEditorRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSelectedDesign(selected);
  }, [selected]);

  const loadSelectedDesign = (design) => {
    console.log("loadSelectedDesign", design);
    // does not work:
    if (emailEditorRef.current && emailEditorRef.current.editor)
      emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(design);
  }

  ...
  const select = () => {
    const fetchSelectedTemplate = async () => {
      const emailTemplate = (
        await dataProvider.getEmailTemplate("XYZ")
      ).data;
      setSelected(emailTemplate);

    };
    fetchSelectedTemplate();
  };

  ...


   <Button onClick={select}>
       Load
   </Button>
   <React.StrictMode>
       <EmailEditor ref={emailEditorRef} onLoad={onLoad} onReady={onReady} options={props.unlayerOptions} />
   </React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself.
It was just a formatting issue when loading the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the results of everything and log it out to the console (even if the function should return void/undefined).

I suspect you simply need to `await` on a promise.

```
await fetchSelectedTemplate()
```

Comment: No, i have already await the result (await dataProvider.getEmailTemplate("XYZ"). This work, the problem is the loadDesign from the emailEditorRef (useRef). I think the problem is the combination useEffect and useRef and Rendering: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values') at editor.js:2".